# Dovecot gmail SSL error

Tags: email, ssl, gmail, dovecot

I'm trying to import all my emails into gmail via POP3, which used to work fine. All of a sudden, I keep getting the following error:

> SSL error: No path found from the leaf certificate to any root. Maybe an intermediate certificate is missing?

I couldn't find anything on the internet. I did manage to track down the only mention of an intermediate certificate in the [dovecot wiki](https://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration), but that's for "Client certificate verification/authentication", which I have disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently hit this issue, using letsencrypt for my certificate, and found that I had mistakenly put a link to cert.pem in my dovecot ssl_cert setting instead of fullchain.pem.

So I was seeing the error you report when my dovecot 10-ssl.conf file had this line in it:

```
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
```

And everything worked when I changed it to this:

```
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
```